# How to delete multiple occurrences of multiple variables in a linked list in c

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am a beginner in c programming and i have been trying for several days to solve the following question:

how to remove numbers that appear at least 3 times in the following list:

3→3→1→2→4→3→5→3→5→4

which makes the result:

1→2→4→5→5→4.

Now i know how to delete multiple occurrences of "one" key in a linked list, for example deleting all occurrences of "1" in the linked list, but can't seem to understand how to delete multiple occurrences of multiple variables. It's just killing me. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do multiple passes over the list. For example one to count all occurrences, and one to remove the nodes.

Comment: So I guess this is an exercise in handling linked lists -- scanning and deleting items and so on.  The simple approach, which does a scan for every key value (and two scans for key values which appear exactly twice).  But that is O(n^2) -- arghhh.  To fix that you need some data structure to collect all the keys a single scan and identify those to delete.  Then do all the deletions in a second scan.  (For extra credit, do it all in one scan.)  Of course, if your list is guaranteed to be "short": Keep It Simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems nobody hurries to help you.:)

It is simpler to write the function if to pass the pointer head to the function by reference.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int insert( struct Node **head, int data )
{
    struct Node *node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;
    }

    return success;
}

void out( struct Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    puts( "null" );
}

void remove_repetitive( struct Node **head )
{
    const size_t LIMIT = 3;

    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        size_t count = 1;

        int data = ( *head )->data;

        for ( struct Node *node = ( *head )->next; 
              count < LIMIT && node != NULL; node = node->next )
        {
            if ( node->data == data ) ++count;
        }

        if ( count == LIMIT )
        {
            for ( struct Node **node = head; *node != NULL; )
            {
                if ( ( *node )->data == data )
                {
                    struct Node *tmp = *node;
                    *node = ( *node )->next;
                    free( tmp );
                }
                else
                {
                    node = &( *node )->next;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    int a[] = { 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3 };

    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        insert( &head, a[i] );
    }

    out( head );

    remove_repetitive( &head );

    out( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 3 -> 5 -> 3 -> 5 -> 4 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 5 -> 4 -> null
```

The function `remove_repetitive` can be splitted out into two functions as it is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int insert( struct Node **head, int data )
{
    struct Node *node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;
    }

    return success;
}

void out( struct Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }
    puts( "null" );
}

void remove_all( struct Node **head, int data )
{
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *head )->data == data )
        {
            struct Node *tmp = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}

void remove_repetitive( struct Node **head )
{
    const size_t LIMIT = 3;

    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        size_t count = 1;

        int data = ( *head )->data;

        for ( struct Node *node = ( *head )->next; 
              count < LIMIT && node != NULL; node = node->next )
        {
            if ( node->data == data ) ++count;
        }

        if ( count == LIMIT )
        {
            remove_all( head, data );   
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    int a[] = { 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3 };

    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        insert( &head, a[i] );
    }

    out( head );

    remove_repetitive( &head );

    out( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

Comment: The logic in your code removes numbers divisible by "3" however the question is "remove elements, that the number of occurrence >= 3."

Comment: yeah that's my problem, i always lose track of the head in the process of deleting occurrences of different variables that appear >= 3 times. In the end the function must return the head of the altered list to the caller.